Center and scale image in div
I'm quite new to CSS and trying to achieve the following (with pure CSS):
I have a fixed div spanning the whole view (container-outer-01).
Inside it, I would like to place another div (container-inner-01) with an image inside.
The second div should be exactly the same size as the image and behave like "object-fit: contain": scale as large as possible without losing the original aspect ratio.
I have the following simple HTML structure (can't change the inner div and the img):


.container-outer-01 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-inner-01 {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: dashed red;
}

.container-inner-01 img {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
<div class="container-outer-01">
  <div class="container-inner-01">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
  </div>
</div>




You can also use display: flex to your container-inner-01 or your img (and don't need max-width or max-height) just set width:100%


.container-outer-01 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-inner-01 {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: dashed red;
}

.container-inner-01 img {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
 }
<div class="container-outer-01">
  <div class="container-inner-01">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for your answer. But if I run your snippet it a) does not scale up and b) if I reduce window height the bottom is cropped by the edge of the window (the window doesn't scale the image down). Tested on edge and ff. Is there any way to achieve that?

Try to use hover, scale, transition. Example for u, my friend link
.container-inner-01 img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .container-inner-01:hover {
    img {
      transform: scale(1.25);
    }
  }

